# AngularJS Route with Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, routes

I was following a Spring Security/AngularJS tutorial to learn the mechanics of it.  I was pretty confident that I had the business logic in place to route from a CSS login page to a CSS-based dashboard page.  Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.ico">

    <title>Sample App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="hello">

    <div ng-controller="loginController as controller" class="container">

        <form role="form" class="form-signin" ng-submit="controller.login()">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" ng-model="controller.credentials.username"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="controller.credentials.password"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/sample.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the sample.js file:

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller : 'loginController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl : 'dashboard.html',
            controller : 'dashboardController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        })
        .otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}).controller('loginController', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $route) {
        var self = this;

        self.tab = function(route) {
            return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
        };

        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

            var headers = credentials ? {
                    authorization : "Basic "
                    + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                        + credentials.password)
                } : {};

            $http.get('user', {
                headers : headers
            }).then(function(response) {
                if (response.data.name) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                }
                callback && callback($rootScope.authenticated);
            }, function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                callback && callback(false);
            });
        }

        authenticate();

        self.credentials = {};
        self.login = function() {
            authenticate(self.credentials, function(authenticated) {
                if (authenticated) {
                    console.log("Login succeeded")
                    $location.path("/dashboard");
                    self.error = false;
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                } else {
                    console.log("Login failed")
                    $location.path("/");
                    self.error = true;
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                }
            })
        };

        self.logout = function() {
            $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            });
        }

    }).controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.go = function () {
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
});
```

The login page (index.html) loads fine when I start the server.  If I login, the URL changes to "http://localhost:8080/?username=user&password=password" but nothing else happens.  Ideally the username and password would not be in the URL....so I would love to know how to eliminate that portion.  But the main issues are getting the dashboard.html page to load when authenticated and also to pass the username to the dashboard.html page so I can use it in the context.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: First, you don't load the angular scripts on this page. Where is the <script> tag for the angularjs? Second, there is no "controller" object in the scope. Maybe you need ng-controller="loginController as controller". If you got this from an example, maybe you should check if you copied it correctly.

Comment: I am a little confused on your feedback.  Are you saying NOT to load angular scripts on the index.html?  And there is no angular.js file in the example I was following so I didn't include it. There was a line for <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> but that file didn't exist, so I assumed it was leftover code.  And I didn't understand the "as controller" portion.  Is that the proper syntax?

Comment: Ok I updated the code above to include the "loginController as controller" and the angularJS that was needed from the WRO configuration.  This fixed the URL issue and when you do Sign-in now it changes the URL to "http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard" but the dashboard.html never loads.  I thought I had the route code syntax correct, but apparently not...what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your "controllerAs" declaration in "when" clauses so actually you don't need "loginController as controller". Just "loginController" is OK. Anyway, it is hard to tell why dashboard is not loading. Use chrome inspector console and make sure no errors. Then check dashboardHtml url is correct in chrome's "network" tab. There must be a network request to this html file. If the url is wrong, consider using <base href="your_base_url_here">And I strongly suggest reading an Angular book because it is really difficult to develop it just by using examples.